# PDF Table Structure While Exporting asp.net to PDF

Tags: c#

I have bellow code to display data in a table. I am trying to display table with left , right, top and bottom border. Within cells there should not have border. The following code displays border left,right and top. how to display bottom border?

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.TotalWidth = 550f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 50f, 30f, 30f, 50f, 50f};
table.SetWidths(widths);
table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
addCell(table, "Product Name");
addCell(table, "System Type");
addCell(table, "Operation");
addCell(table, "Quality");
addCell(table, "Price");


addNewCell(table,"Mobile",1,0,0,0);
addNewCell(table, "A", 0, 0, 0, 0);
addNewCell(table, "O1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
addNewCell(table, "A1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
addNewCell(table, "100", 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

and addNewCell() and addCell() are like:-

```
private static void addCell(PdfPTable table, string text)
    {
         BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
         iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
         PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, times));
         cell.Right = 0;
         cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
         cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
         Color myColor = WebColors.GetRGBColor("#F7FF00");
         cell.BackgroundColor = myColor;
         table.AddCell(cell);
    }
    private static void addNewCell(PdfPTable table, string text,int bordersizeleft,int borderright,int bordertop,int borderbottom)
    {
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, times));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        //table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        cell.BorderWidthLeft = bordersizeleft;
        cell.BorderWidthRight = borderright;
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = borderbottom;
        cell.BorderWidthTop = bordertop;
        table.AddCell(cell);

    }
```

Please help me to get bottom border

[image]

Comment: Your sample code does not match the sample output you're showing. And in your sample code you're not setting a bottom border on any of the calls to addNewCell(). So it's difficult to give advice when you don't provide usable information.

Comment: Thanks. But there's still no calls to addNewCell() where you specify a bottom border.

Comment: thats what i want to know. How to get bottom border?

Comment: Um, well, just looking at the addNewCell() method's signature, I'd guess you should call it with the value "1" as the last argument. For example "addNewCell(table, "500", 0, 1, 0, 1)".

Comment: No I wont get if it is 1. I used  cell.DisableBorderSide();  and got the result as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used

```
cell.DisableBorderSide()//Method
```

to get bottom border in addNewCell().